# Autocomplete suggestion and search using json data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

```js
class _AutoCompleteDemoState extends State < AutoCompleteDemo > {
  AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField;

  List < DoAwaitedList > doawaitedlist;
  String query = '';

  TextEditingController tc;
  bool loading = true;

  List < DoAwaitedList > autocomFromJson(String str) =>
  List < DoAwaitedList > .from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => DoAwaitedList.fromJson(x)));
  String payloadToJson(List < DoAwaitedList > data) =>
  json.encode(List < dynamic > .from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));


  Future < List < DoAwaitedList >> requestMethodtest() async {
    var url = "";
    var body = json.encode({ });
    Map < String, String > headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      loading = true;
      doawaitedlist = autocomFromJson(response.body);
      loading = false;
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('USerrrlist$responseJson');
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
    return doawaitedlist;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestMethodtest();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        title: new Text('AutoComplte'),
        backgroundColor: Color(getColorHexFromStr("#00324B")),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: < Widget > [


            new AutoCompleteTextField < > (
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search:",
                suffixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search)),
              itemSubmitted: (item) => setState(() => selected = item),
              key: key,
              suggestions: suggestions,
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) => new Padding(
                child: new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(suggestion.name),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
              itemSorter: (a, b) => a.stars == b.stars ? 0 : a.stars > b.stars ? -1 : 1,
              itemFilter: (suggestion, input) =>
              suggestion.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: loading && doawaitedlist == null ?
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Loading...'),
                  leading: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ) :
                doawaitedlist == null ?
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Loading...'),
                  leading: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ) :
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: doawaitedlist == null ? 0 : doawaitedlist[0].rows.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class DoAwaitedList {
  int status;
  String msg;
  List < Rows > rows;
  String sql;
  dynamic reserved;

  DoAwaitedList({
    this.status,
    this.msg,
    this.rows,
    this.sql,
    this.reserved,
  });

  factory DoAwaitedList.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) => DoAwaitedList(
    status: json["status"],
    msg: json["msg"],
    rows: List < Rows > .from(json["rows"].map((x) => Rows.fromJson(x))),
    sql: json["sql"],
    reserved: json["reserved"],
  );

  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "msg": msg,
    "rows": List < dynamic > .from(rows.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "sql": sql,
    "reserved": reserved,
  };
}
class Rows {
  String CustName;
  String CustCode;
  Rows({
    this.CustName,
    this.CustCode,
  });

  factory Rows.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) => Rows(
    CustName: json["CustName"],
    CustCode: json["CustCode"],
  );
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => {
    "CustName": CustName,
    "CustCode": CustCode,
  };
}
```

I want to implement autocomplete textfield display data from api call (i.e json data) in list as suggestions when user types in a textfield. The suggestions displayed should be based on id that is associated with text to be displayed. Somehow I am not able to achieve to display the data in UI and how to build the hierarchy of widgets that will display suggestions in list. Not sure what am I missing here. Looking for guidance. End result I am looking to achieve is. Any help is appreciated.[![

[image]

```js
Json snippet:

  [{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "Ok",
    "refcode": -1,
    "trows": 771,
    "rows": [{
        "CustName": "ELECTRICALS SYSTEM",
        "CustCode": "1F",

      },
      {
        "CustName": "ELECTRICALS",
        "CustCode": "2R",

      },
      {
        "CustName": "GABL CFH",
        "CustCode": "2T",

      }

    ],
    "sql": "User",
    "reserved": null
  }]
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield

Comment: @NaveenAvidi tried out this thing bt not getting ..!! actually json array is nested so iam not getting how to implement it with the widget.it will be helpfull if you will explain me with some code

Answer (score 0):

At present I dont have an sdk , so I used dartpad to the below alternative.
Also you can do the same with Autocomplete..... using JSON data

```
List<Map> jsonData = [{
        "status": 200,
        "msg": "Ok",
        "refcode": -1,
        "trows": 771,
        "rows": [{
            "CustName": "ELECTRICALS SYSTEM",
            "CustCode": "1F",

          },
          {
            "CustName": "ELECTRICALS",
            "CustCode": "2R",

          },
          {
            "CustName": "GABL CFH",
            "CustCode": "2T",

          }

        ],
        "sql": "User",
        "reserved": null
      }];

      List<Map> rows=[];
      String query = '';
      TextEditingController tc;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        tc = TextEditingController();
        rows = jsonData[0]['rows'];
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            body: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Positioned(
                      top: 70,
                      child:
                          Column(children: [Text('Other Widgets goes here...!')])),
                  Column(children: [
                    TextField(
                        controller: tc,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search...'),
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          setState(() {
                            query = v;
                          });
                        }),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: rows.length,
                            itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
                              return query.trim().isEmpty
                                  ? null
                                  : rows[ind]['CustName'].toString()
                                          .toLowerCase()
                                          .contains(query.toLowerCase())
                                      ? ListTile(
                                          title: Text(rows[ind]['CustName']),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              tc.text = rows[ind]['CustName'];
                                              query = rows[ind]['CustName'];
                                            });
                                          })
                                      : null;
                            }))
                  ]),
                ])));
      }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i have edited my code which i done ..... can you help me with that ... i have tried urs ... bt i am not getting ...

Comment: Do u assigning values to suggestions variable ??

Comment: not Assigning ...passing the list variable to the suggestions. @NaveenAvidi

Comment: new AutoCompleteTextField<DoAwaitedList>
 (
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Search:",
              suffixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search)),
                itemSubmitted: (item) => setState(() => selected = item),
          key: key,
          suggestions: doawaitedlist ,
          controller: tc,
),

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I tried this method but I'm getting some error after performing multiple searches. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299018/how-to-perform-a-text-search-over-json-data-in-flutter) to the question I posted. Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Some one is already answered you ! Make pagination if ur data is huge !

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Also, the data isn't huge at all. For now, I'm just using dummy data even that is causing problem.

Comment: Hi !! I added an answer ! Please check it !